# Liferay - NTLM SSO and LDAP

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

Liferay supports NTLM SSO using a set of properties that I have to configure in portal-ext.properties.

I have a set of users who are internal employees on Internal AD and bunch of external users on External AD.

Is it possible to have just NTLM SSO for internal employees and External users have to key in credentials? If so how?

For external users on External AD, can I use Liferay's password policy? Does it require any code change?

For external users, if they updated "password" and certain LDAP attributes that are mapped to Liferay's custom Attributes from Liferay, will it automatically sync to LDAP?

Does any of the above require code change or I can manage everything from Control Panel and portal-ext.properties?

If the above setting is possible to have half of the users authenticated automatically using Windows Authentication and half providing credentials, how would I identify when a user who is Internal User, comes through a vpn and is not using his company laptop?

Comment: Which SSO product are you using?

Comment: NTLM SSO https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integration+with+NTLM+plus+ADS

Comment: I see, but it would be better to use a proper SSO product in this case. You require multiple ways of authenticating the users. If you implement it in liferay, it would be very complex and error-prone.